# Push Notification Trigger on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm working on the "feature" the push notification trigger available in Windows phone 8.1. My goal is to make this work with a Windows phone Silverlight 8.1 project. As far as I know, it should work based on my reading.

After 2 days, I'm totally stuck. No matter what i'm trying. When I send a raw notification to my app, my app is canceled and I'm back to the windows menu.

The output :
The program '[1852] BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[2712] AgHost.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

State :

- The app receives the notification. It trigger OnPushNotificationReceived. (After this event, the app is canceled)
- The Push Notification task is declared and the entry point is defined to **Push.Notification**.
- I create a Windows Runtime Component for Windows phone 8.1 in order to run the background task.
- The background task is well registered.

---

```
private async void RegisterBackgroundTask()
{
    UnregisterBackgroundTask(taskName);
    BackgroundAccessStatus backgroundStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
    if (backgroundStatus != BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied && backgroundStatus != BackgroundAccessStatus.Unspecified)
    {
        try
        {
            BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            taskBuilder.Name = taskName;
            PushNotificationTrigger trigger = new PushNotificationTrigger();
            taskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);
            taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = "Push.Notification";
            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = taskBuilder.Register();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```

- The background task :

---

```
public sealed class Notification
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Background starting...");
        Debug.WriteLine("Background completed!");
    }
}
```

I have no clue about what I'm doing wrong.
Is there someone who make it works ? (Not in theory)
For information, I have 2 warnings that worrying me :

- I have a mismatch in the process architecture in my 2 projects. My windows phone project use "Any CPU" (can"t change that). My windows runetime component project use "ARM". If I use "Any CPU" wor my WinRT, i got an errror :
  */platform:anycpu32bitpreferred can only be used with /t:exe, /t:winexe and /t:appcontainerexe*
- There is a conflict on a dependent assembly of the 2 projects. Seems to be

Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not use the SignalR framework to make push notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally make it works.

There was an error in my initial code I forgot to implement IBackgroundTask :

```
public sealed class Notification : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Background starting...");
        Debug.WriteLine("Background completed!");
    }
}
```

And I had to make my Task async...

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    // perform your async task and then call deferral  complete
    await Test();
    deferral.Complete();
}

private static async Task Test()
{
    //TODO with an await
}
```

Hope this'll help someone.